# Accessing JS dictionary gives undefined

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, websocket

I am trying to present some data received in a stream in a table. I am using the following code for this:

```
function notify(data){
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(actual_JSON["Pipekey"]+" - "+actual_JSON["workdate"]+" total: "+actual_JSON);
}
```

For the time being just checking and reporting the values.
And this is the console output for each row:

> undefined - undefined total: {"Pipekey":1521,"workdate":"01/12/2016
>   08:51:00","measurement":{"order":201794,"heat":4043,"lot":12,"tube":1,"wallThickness":6.246,"outletDiameter":89,"length":10000}}

Why cannot I access the member of the dictionary by value and how may I do it instead?

I was hinted the problem was with some irregular character in the parsed data and so I am also including the code in the server sending the data by WebSocket:

```
function multiStep(myConnection, data) {
    var i=0;
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    myTimer=setInterval(function() {
        console.log("eseguo il timer "+i+"/"+data.length);
        if (i<data.length){
            var element=JSON.stringify(data[i]);
            console.log("provo a mandare elemento: "+element);
            try {
                myConnection.send(element);
                console.log("mandato elemento");
            } catch(err) {
                console.log('Websocket error: %s', err);
                i=data.length;
                clearInterval(myTimer);
            }
            i++;
        } else {
            console.log("finito il loop");
            clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

I also tried to print the ascii of all the charecters of the string but failed to find anything irregular in the point where the user reported to be:

```
app.js:58 str:0 ascii:48
app.js:58 str:4 ascii:52
app.js:58 str:3 ascii:51
app.js:58 str:, ascii:44
app.js:58 str:\ ascii:92
app.js:58 str:" ascii:34
app.js:58 str:l ascii:108
app.js:58 str:o ascii:111
app.js:58 str:t ascii:116
app.js:58 str:\ ascii:92
app.js:58 str:" ascii:34
app.js:58 str:: ascii:58
app.js:58 str:1 ascii:49
app.js:58 str:2 ascii:50
app.js:58 str:, ascii:44
```

but for a funny change of color just where the control character ought to be.
While if I copy the string in the post to Notepad+ the actual control character is actually displayed by moving the pointer.
So I am quite puzzled as I do not know where this character comes from and how to get rid of it if ever listing the ascii of the chars does not list it but conversely interprets it to change the color of the display.

Comment: Please check if its not an array of object. Try `Array.isArray(actual_JSON)`

Comment: Is your actual_JSON var an object? It being a string would explain your problem. try `console.log(typeof actual_JSON);`

I'm pretty sure it's a string as `console.log` -ing it would print [object Object] instead of what you want

Comment: `typeof actual_JSON`? The only sensible thing I can think of is that true to its name it's _actually_ JSON which is a string.

Comment: You are right, it is a string, but why it is so if a parsed it?

Comment: This is the data before the parse:
original data"{\"Pipekey\":1521,\"workdate\":\"01/12/2016 08:51:00\",\"measurement\":{\"order\":201794,\"heat\":4043,\"lot\":12,\"tube\":1,\"wallThickness\":6.246,\"outletDiameter\":89,\"length\":10000}}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was trivially due to an excess stringfy when relaying the data from the index file to the frames. Once removed it Json could parse it fine and return an object.

Answer (score 0):

Your data contains some corrupted chars. If you take the snippet below and edit it you'll see some floating red dots (as in `​\‌·​"lot\":12` and `\"tube\":1‌​·`) in the data string that has been commented out. The data string below that one has a clean version of the same data and it works ok.

```js
function notify(data){
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(actual_JSON["Pipekey"]+" - "+actual_JSON["workdate"]+" total: "+actual_JSON);
}
/*
data = "{\"Pipekey\":1521,\"workdate\":\"01/12/2016 08:51:00\",\"measurement\":{\"order\":201794,\"heat\":4043,\‌​"lot\":12,\"tube\":1‌​,\"wallThickness\":6‌​.246,\"outletDiamete‌​r\":89,\"length\":10‌​000}}";
*/
data = "{\"Pipekey\":1521,\"workdate\":\"01/12/2016 08:51:00\",\"measurement\":{\"order\":201794,\"heat\":4043, \"lot\":12,\"tube\":1,\"wallThickness\":6.246,\"outletDiamete‌r\":89,\"length\":10000}}";
notify(data);
```

Comment: It may be so, thanks, but I receive those data from a server that on its part has stringified its own array, without me editing the result in any way .I do not of any way to force stringfy to add spaces in random places of its output. Without even knowing which field creates problems... I am adding the server code for your reference.

Comment: Also, how do I visualise those corrupted chars somehow included?

Comment: At the very least please tell me how to detect the corrupted chars so that I may check at which step they are created.

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci I detected those chars on this site, using the snippet tool. I could not see them on my usuall editor (Atom). I really don't know how to detect them outside SO. But on SO they showed up and when removed the code worked great.

Comment: That does not mean the code is like that from the origin. The original JSON may be ok and got corrupted later on (copy/paste, transformation functions, ...)